# Change the color of the upward arrow on an open dropdown-menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with twitter bootstrap 2.0.1

I'm trying to change the color of the dropdown-menu.

I have managed to change the color of the container that is comming down itself, however I can't seem the find where the arrow is comming from.

Anyone know where I can find the code where the arrow comes from (and how to change it's color)?

[image: examle]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The arrow code can be found on `line:2690` of the `bootstrap.css`. You can manipulate its position and color by modifying its css, e.g.:

```
.navbar .dropdown-menu:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #000; /* change color here, modified for a black arrow */
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Update for Bootstrap 4.4 (year 2020): Use

```
<style>
.navbar .dropdown-toggle::after{ color:red; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the latest Version of Bootstrap (v2.3.1), this has changed. It's now on line 694

```
.navbar .nav>li>.dropdown-menu:after{
content:'';
display:inline-block;
border-left:6px solid transparent;
border-right:6px solid transparent;
border-bottom:6px solid #ffffff;
position:absolute;
top:-6px
;left:10px;
}
```