# Bootstrap 3: Custom color for select dropdown arrow

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to change the color of the dropdown arrow in a Bootstrap 3 dropdown select.

Here's my CSS so far, I already changed the background, border, font and option colors, but have had no luck with the arrow yet:

```
select{
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
select:after {
  color: white !important;
}
option:checked {
  background-color: #eee;
  color:#555;
}
option:not(:checked) {
  background-color: white;
  color:#000;
}
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ju3n1dnk/**

Comment: Can you create a demo fiddle?

Comment: @Etash here's the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ju3n1dnk/

Comment: did you tried http://uplifted.net/programming/change-default-select-dropdown-style-just-css/?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611482/change-color-and-appearance-of-drop-down-arrow

Comment: You can find a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329044/change-the-color-of-the-upward-arrow-on-an-open-dropdown-menu

Answer (score 3):

You want to change the color of the down arrow in the dropdown?
As far as I know, this arrow is coded like that :

```
<span class="caret"></span>
```

So if you want to change the color of this, you just have to add the color property :

```
.caret{ color: red; }
```

**Update**

Here's a JSFiddle to illustrate : https://jsfiddle.net/valentinho14/tkfa0ddp/

Answer (score -1):

just update color for select

```
select {
    color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap use 'background-image' for the dropdown arrow. So simply change the background image.

```
.form-select{
background-image:url(....);
}
```

Comment: This may be true for later versions of Bootstrap, but isn't for Bootstrap 3.